# Replicate each time with different standard deviation

Tags: r

I have a vector of standard deviations:

`sd_vec<-runif(10,0,20)` with 10 values between 0 and 20.

```
[1] 11.658106  9.693493 12.695608  4.091922  5.761061 18.410951 14.710990 12.095944 18.023123
[10] 13.294963
```

I would like to replicate the following process:

```
a<-rnorm(10,0,30)
[1] -21.265083  85.557147  23.958170 -32.843328   6.629831 -23.745339  46.094324  51.020059
[9]   1.041724  13.757235

n_columns=50
replicate(n_columns, a+rnorm(length(a), mean=0,sd=sd_vec))
```

The result should be 10 columns each of which are:

```
column 1: a + rnorm(length(a),0,11.658106)
column 2: a + rnorm(length(a),0,9.693493)
column 3: a + rnorm(length(a),0,12.695608)
.
.
.
column 10:a + rnorm(length(a),0,13.294963)
```

Will this use different values of `sd_vec` for each replication or will it use it for each random number generation?

Comment: something like this `replicate(n_columns, a+sapply(sd_vec, rnorm, n=100, mean=0))`?

Comment: but will these use the same standard deviation for each replication (i.e. column) or will it use a different one for each value?

Comment: It replicates 10 times using the same sd and allocates this in the third dimension of the array, say `X[,,1]`, then it'll pick the second sd and replicates 10 times and put the result in `X[,,2]` and so on until the 10th sd producing 10 replicates and allocating them in `X[,,10]` :D

Comment: great, but why is this an array why not a matrix?

Comment: You can choose the first replicates for each sd by doing `X[,1,]` it'll be a matrix. If you want just a matrix consisting of one column for each sd, then not use `replicate`

Comment: see my edit. I tried to make it more clear what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution will replicate `sd_vec` for each replication, not using each sd for each replication.

If you want to have columns for each sd then you may work on matrices. Create matrix of `rnorm` with desire sd by:

```
X <- rnorm(length(a)*n_columns, mean=0, sd=sd_vec)
X <- matrix(X, nrow=length(a), ncol=n_columns, byrow=TRUE)
```

Then add it to `a` converted to matrix:

```
matrix(a, nrow=length(a), ncol=n_columns) + X
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your edit, then you may want to try

```
 a+sapply(sd_vec, rnorm, n=100, mean=0)

# example
> set.seed(1)
> sd_vec <-runif(10,0,20)
> set.seed(1)  
> a<-rnorm(100,0,30)
> n_columns=10 
> head(a+sapply(sd_vec, rnorm, n=100, mean=0))
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]      [,7]       [,8]       [,9]
[1,] -22.087869 -15.746650 -8.554735   0.7226986 -18.481801 -24.921835 -32.16206 -33.158153 -38.187974
[2,]   5.732942  18.078702 -6.489666  39.9422684   4.311839  32.504554  42.75921 -18.624133   7.954302
[3,] -29.906010 -13.260709 -2.483113 -36.0217953 -29.841630 -15.576334 -26.76925 -11.915258 -21.741820
[4,]  48.697584  45.395650 43.463125  40.7586401  47.903975  57.600406  47.59359  47.701659  33.782184
[5,]   6.409275  -7.122582 28.836887   2.3249113  13.884993   7.429514 -11.34081   1.960571  18.075706
[6,] -15.229450  -6.025260 -7.288529 -31.4375515 -18.184563 -45.038651 -50.00938 -26.965804 -37.610292
          [,10]
[1,] -17.391109
[2,]   6.883342
[3,] -26.144900
[4,]  48.118830
[5,]   9.970987
[6,] -26.668629
```